# Angularjs ag-grid header cell click event is not firing up

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ag-grid

In ag-grid, one of the header columns I have the following :

```
 headerCellRenderer : function(params) {
                        params.$scope.assignRegHrsInput = "";
                        return '<span>' + data.headerName + '</span></br><input class="exp-param-header-input"  type="text" ng-model="assignRegHrsInput"> </br> <span ng-click="changeAllAssignedRegHrs(assignRegHrsInput)"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span> Apply To All</span>'
                    }
```

And I have

```
 $scope.changeAllAssignedRegHrs = function(tobeChanged) {
   alert(tobeChanged);
 }
```

But the when I click the above span element click event is not firing up. Can any help me how to fix it?

In my grid options I have specified :

```
angularCompileRows: true,
angularCompileHeaders: true
```

But still the ng-click event on the span is not firing up.

In the browser console, I can see my header for this span as shown below:

```
<span class="ng-scope">
<span>R Hours</span>
<br>
<input class="exp-param-header-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="text" ng-model="assignRegHrsInput">
<br>
<span ng-click="changeAllAssignedRegHrs(assignRegHrsInput)">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>
Apply To All
</span>
</span>
```

Comment: what is your header look like? can you see "Apply To All" and clicked on that text?

Comment: I have edited my question with the way my header looks like in the browser. You can see in that html, ng-clik is there

Comment: if you put `ng-click="changeAllAssignedReg....` on `<span>R Hours</span>`, will it work? also which version of ag-grid are you using?

Comment: Yes, even then the same problem. The event is not firing up. I am using ag-grid, @version v1.11.1

Comment: strange, it looks like ok on that particular version too - http://rawgit.com/S-YOU/ag-docs/master/1.11.1/angular-grid-header-rendering/example1.html

Comment: Not sure this is the cause, I have put ag-grid in separate directive and passing grid options to that directive. So now, when I wrote in my headerCellRenderer, as params.changeAllAssignedRegHrs = function()..., the click event is firing up. So from here inside this function I am calling another function in my controller and it has solved the problem.

Comment: Now  for cellRenderer, I have an input box, when I wrote ng-blur and call function in the same way as I described above, it is not firing up. I am not sure how it work for ng-clik on span in the header but failing ng-blur event for input box in cellRenderer. Any solution for this?

Comment: i think you need $timeout of ng-blur - check javascript source of example of that page - http://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-editing/index.php.

Comment: do you have any sample reference code for that?

Answer (score 1):

In `headerCellRenderer`, using it as `params.changeAllAssignedRegHrs = function() {}`, should solve the problem of firing the on `ng-click`.